# Error in install.packages : type =="both" cannot be used with 'repos =NULL'

Tags: r, zip, package, install.packages, binaries

Actually I am trying to install packages offline. I have R studio. what I do is based on previously asked question as follows:

```
install.packages(C:/Users/Desktop/class_7.3-12.zip", repos = NULL)
```

I get the error I mentioned in the title. is someone out there to give me an advice ?

Thanks

Comment: Add `,  type="binary"` to your command.

Comment: Btw, you noticed the missing `"`, right..?

Comment: Sure but that is just a typo. The error comes from the changes default of `type="both" in R 3.2.0.

Comment: I cannot load it. If I type library(shinyapps-master), it says _Error in library("shinyapps-master") : 
  there is no package called ‘shinyapps-master’_

Answer (score 10):

You can install packages from source or binaries. In the "Package Archives" section of the documentation you may read:

> Package Source    class_7.3-12.tar.gz
>
> Windows Binary    class_7.3-12.zip
>
> (32- & 64-bit) Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)  class_7.3-12.tgz

When installing from binary (as it seems to be your case):

```
install.packages("class_7.3-12.zip", repos = NULL, type="binary")
```

Otherwise, when installing from source:

```
install.packages("class_7.3-12.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

Comment: Try to install "devtools", it solved me the same problem:        ```install.packages("devtools")```