# Install local package from zip archive

Tags: r, zip, package, install.packages

How can I install a package from a zip file in R?  I'm using the tools > install packages then selecting the install from 'Package Archive File (.zip, .tar.gz)' option.  However an error message occurs.  I have devtools installed, so the console window looks like this:

```
library("devtools", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.2")
install.packages("C:/Users/noodl/Downloads/RPUX/rpux_0.5.1/rpud_0.5.1.zip", repos = NULL)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/noodl/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

> Error in install.packages : type == "both" cannot be used with 'repos = NULL'

I'm using R version 3.2

Comment: Duplicate of the (admittedly badly-named) ["Error in install.packages : type ==“both” cannot be used with 'repos =NULL'"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123786/error-in-install-packages-type-both-cannot-be-used-with-repos-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common question ... so common, in fact, I didn't immediately find a SO question that was actually answered in an *answer* vice a comment. The most recent I found was @DirkEddelbuettel's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123786/error-in-install-packages-type-both-cannot-be-used-with-repos-null): add `type="binary"` to your command.

Comment: Right, but the naming of ["Error in install.packages : type ==“both” cannot be used with 'repos =NULL'"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123786/error-in-install-packages-type-both-cannot-be-used-with-repos-null) is poor and the naming of this question is very clear.