# Execution halted - no package called ‘rgeolocate’ [R]

Tags: r, package

I am not able to knit my document in PDF format since I executed the following:

```
setme <- 
"Sys.setenv(TZ='America/New_York') #some default not get any errors
invisible(loadNamespace('rgeolocate'))
invisible(loadNamespace('httr'))
mytz <- rgeolocate::ip_api(httr::content(httr::GET('https://api.ipify.org?format=json'))[1])[['timezone']]
Sys.setenv(TZ=mytz)"

cat(setme,file=file.path(R.home(),'etc/Rprofile.site'),sep='\n')
```

from: https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-sys-setenv-does-not-persist/2105/16

In R Markdown, it prints the following message:

```
Error in loadNamespace("rgeolocate") : 
  there is no package called ‘rgeolocate’
Execution halted
```

> Do you know what is the reason for such message?
>
> I regret having executed these lines. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [rgeolocate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgeolocate/index.html) package from [GitHub](https://github.com/Ironholds/rgeolocate) rather than from CRAN.

```
# install developmental version from GitHub
devtools::install_github( repo = "ironholds/rgeolocate" )
```

Answer for the question partially comes from @Steven Wink from his answer to the question [Error in R: (Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249980/error-in-r-package-which-is-only-available-in-source-form-and-may-need-compil) and @Hugues Fontenelle and his answer to the question [Error in install.packages : type =="both" cannot be used with 'repos =NULL'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123786/error-in-install-packages-type-both-cannot-be-used-with-repos-null).

Comment: I did, then it prints:`Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran:
  ‘rgeolocate’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?` I say yes, but the issue is not fixed. Nothing changes.

Comment: Does it give you the option to hit 'Y' or 'N'? If so, hit 'Y'.

Comment: Yes I hit 'y', but it still shows the same error message.

Comment: Okay, let me update my answer. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Since I executed this code `setme <- 
"Sys.setenv(TZ='America/New_York')  
invisible(loadNamespace('rgeolocate'))
invisible(loadNamespace('httr'))
mytz <- rgeolocate::ip_api(httr::content(httr::GET('https://api.ipify.org?format=json'))[1])[['timezone']]
Sys.setenv(TZ=mytz)"

cat(setme,file=file.path(R.home(),'etc/Rprofile.site'),sep='\n')` from: https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-sys-setenv-does-not-persist/2105/16   I got this error message and not able to knit document anymore. I have so much regret executing these lines.

Comment: All is definitely not lost. I would recommend reading the comments to the SO post I linked to in my question. It walks you through some behind the scenes tools you may or may not have on your operating system.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your solution and printed the following: **Error in install.packages : type == "both" cannot be used with 'repos = NULL'**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165861/discussion-between-aspiringurbandatascientist-and-zizou23).